# Moment js Use localtime for Fromnow() using Java Script

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to find time ago in my html page, but the time considered for calculating is Greenwich meridian time.

I am currently trying

```
moment.utc(date).fromNow();
```

I tried to get time in my local zone using `.tz('Asia/Kolkata')` and tried:

```
moment.utc(date).from(moment(new Date()).tz('Asia/kolkata').format('llll'));
```

This still takes Greenwich meridian time to calculate.

EDIT
'date' is sent by node js server in a JSON There as well date is calculated using `var date = moment(new Date()).tz('Asia/kolkata').format('llll')`.

For Me localtime is 'Asia/Kolkota'

Comment: What does the `date` denotes in your `moment.utc(date).fromNow();` statement?

Comment: What is `date` value? Are you using `moment.utc(date)` instead of `moment(date)` for any particular reason? Can you detail further what you are getting and what you want? The result should be in `'Asia/Kolkata'` timezone or in local time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is you're trying to get momentJs to interpret a datetime string that isnt in a format that it can recognise (by using `.format('llll')`).

If you're trying to get the difference in time between the UTC of a given date, and the current `Asia\Kolkata` time. You're best to try something like:

```
// get "now" in Asia Kolkata and format into a string that Moment will understand
var dateFromServer = moment(new Date()).tz('Asia/kolkata').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
// to see a much different time try:
//var dateFromServer = moment('2016-12-31 15:00:00').tz('Asia/kolkata').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

// on client get "now" in Asia Kolkata
var nowInKolkata = moment().tz('Asia/kolkata');
// output string from "server"
dateOutput.innerHTML = 'date from "server": ' + dateFromServer;
// output difference between time "now" in Asia Kolkata, and the UTC version of the server date
result.innerHTML = nowInKolkata.from(moment.utc(dateFromServer));
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v2qkbmvx/2/)**

Comment: For a date that is Present and Couple of seconds ago it is showing as five hours Ago

Comment: you're comparing the `utc` time to the time in `Asia/Kolkata`.. Asia/Kolkata is +5.5hours, `.from()` doesnt show half hours when displaying number of hours

Comment: if you are trying to get the time between two dates, they should probably be the same timezone.. ie. either dont use `.utc()` in the output difference, or use `.utc()` on the date from the server, your original question seemed to imply you wanted the server dates to be offset by the timezone too